api returns null when redirected in spring data jpa
i was trying to make a simple board with spring boot and data jpa that users can make a post and admins can make boards. this is the code of api i made that creates a board.
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<BoardResponseDto> createBoard(@RequestBody @Validated BoardNameRequestDto boardNameRequestDto) {
        long boardId = boardService.createBoard(boardNameRequestDto);

        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/board/" + boardId))
                .body(
                        BoardResponseDto.builder()
                                .code(ms.getMessage("suc.code", null, null))
                                .message(ms.getMessage("suc.message", null, null))
                                .build()
                );
}

uri over there is mapped with board details page. so when i send my request, it should create a board and redirect to board details page of the board that i created.
and this is the code of board details page.
@GetMapping("/{boardId}")
    public ResponseEntity<BoardResponseDto> getBoard(@PathVariable long boardId, Pageable pageable) {
        Board findBoard = boardService.findBoard(boardId).orElseThrow(NoBoardException::new);

        List<PostListDto> boardPost = postService.getBoardPost(boardId, pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                BoardResponseDto.builder()
                        .code(ms.getMessage("suc.code", null, null))
                        .message(ms.getMessage("suc.message", null, null))
                        .boardName(findBoard.getBoardName())
                        .postCount(boardPost.size())
                        .postList(boardPost)
                        .build()
        );
}

so this is actual response of board details page and the expected response of redirection from creating a board.
{
    "code": "SUC",
    "message": "Success",
    "boardName": "test",
    "postCount": 0,
    "postList": []
}

but this is what i actually got when i send a request to create a board.
{
    "code": "SUC",
    "message": "Success",
    "boardName": null,
    "postCount": 0,
    "postList": null
}

as far as i know redirecting to a page is same as accessing to the page with GET method, but it seems to be different.. help me please. sorry about my poor english

I hope I understood your question correctly:
When you send a request to your POST endpoint, you want the resource to be created and then redirect to your GET endpoint?
You can do this as follows if you want to use a ResponseEntity:
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createBoard(@RequestBody @Validated BoardNameRequestDto boardNameRequestDto) {
        long boardId = boardService.createBoard(boardNameRequestDto);
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Location", "/board/" + boardId);    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

Or simplified without ResponseEntity:
    @PostMapping
    public String createBoard(@RequestBody @Validated BoardNameRequestDto boardNameRequestDto) {
        long boardId = boardService.createBoard(boardNameRequestDto);
        
        return "redirect:/board/" + boardId;
    }

As a third alternative without a redirect, you can also call your Get method:
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<BoardResponseDto> createBoard(@RequestBody @Validated BoardNameRequestDto boardNameRequestDto) {
        long boardId = boardService.createBoard(boardNameRequestDto);
        
        return getBoard(boardId, PageRequest.of(0, 5));
    }

Note: the first two solutions will send a HTTP 301 (FOUND) and acctualy redirect you to the GET endpoint. The third method will directly return your data with HTTP 200 (OK).

i think my question is bit misunderstood sry for my poor english. my problem was that the redirection isn't working as i expected. redirection itself does work correctly, as location header in created httpstatus intends to. but the result of the redirection, which is a result with null value in boardName, postList attribute, is different with what i expected.

Does it work if you manually call the GET endpoint after the POST endpoint? Otherwise it looks to me like there might be a bug in your boardService.findBoard method or the boardService.createBoard method. After creating a board, have you checked whether the name and boardPost are actually present in the database?
